# Idiom meaning 'a shambles' sounds like /pass potch/?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I'm looking for an idiom that means 'a shambles' or 'a whole mess of various things', and any other reverse definitions of 'a whole mess of various things'.  Perhaps "a mare's nest", which I've gathered from google:'shambles', is one of them?

Comment: Not an answer as it doesn't fulfil the title's criteria, but my current favourite, only recently learned, is "Bugger's Muddle". If you haven't come across it I should say that despite inclusion of the vulgarity "Bugger's...", it has no direct vulgar meaning associated with that word, it's just a lovely phrase meaning really *really* convoluted mess!

Comment: @MarvMills Was it in Norfolk, by any chance that you heard 'bugger's muddle'. It is a great favourite there.

Comment: No I first heard it in Maidstone of all places, but the perp could have been from Norfolk I guess. But since then I've heard it in several places in London so maybe it's spreading?

Comment: There's also 'to make a pig's ear' of something.

Comment: @MarvMills Or, if you're a fan of Spongebob, Mr. Krabs says: "barnacle's bunghole" all the time.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 "Barnacle's _bunghole_"?! I'll admit that I haven't seen many of the more recent episodes, but... _bunghole_? I have a very hard time believing that. Mr. Krabs says "barnacles!" all the time, but I've never heard "barnacle's bunghole." Source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Hodgepodge](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hodgepodge#Noun)*, *[hotchpotch](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hotchpotch#Noun)*, and *[mishmash](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mishmash#Noun)* already have been mentioned, but you still may find the [Wikisaurus page](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wikisaurus:hodgepodge) for the sense  “collection containing a confused variety of miscellaneous things” of interest.  Synonyms listed there are:

> farrago, gallimaufry, hodgepodge, hotchpotch, jumble, medley, melange, mingle-mangle, mishmash, mixed bag, mixture, motley, oddments, omnium-gatherum, pastiche, potpourri, ragbag, slurry, smorgasbord, Whitman's sampler

The Wikisaurus page also shows hypernyms *collection* and *group*, and [meronyms](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/meronym#Noun)  *bits and bobs*, *dribs and drabs*, *odds and ends*, *odds and sods*.

*Edit:* For additional terms:
(1) Follow the links from those words on the Wikisaurus page and read the entries and follow the links from those words, etc.; for example, the *[gallimaufry](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gallimaufry#Noun)* entry mentions  “Any absurd medley” and the terms *[hash](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hash#Noun)* (which has as one sense “A confused mess”) and  *[ragout](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ragout#Noun)* (“a stew of meat and vegetables mixed together”, as might be served in some messes).
(2) Put some of the terms into the search box at [onelook's reverse dictionary](http://www.onelook.com/reverse-dictionary.shtml) and follow the links, etc.  For example, starting with *jumble* gets you a list of 65 words; many are irrelevant, but some (eg *muddle, welter, mare's nest, imbroglio, goulash, macaronic, word salad*) may be useful.  Eg, from [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mare%27s_nest), *mare's nest* has a sense “A confused or complicated situation; a muddle”.  (Note, [reverse lookup](http://www.onelook.com/?w=*&loc=revfp2&clue=a+messy+pile) for  “a messy pile” returns hundreds of words, with the vast majority irrelevant; but some search tuning may be possible.)

Comment: Thanks for all the synonyms.  Do you any other words that traditionally meant 'a messy pile'?  I think I read that imbroglio used to mean that in an LSAT vocab book.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08, see edit

Answer (score 2):

[hotchpotch](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define:%20hotchpotch)

> "a confused mixture"

aka 'hodgepodge'

Answer (score 1):

I often use **mishmash** to describe this. I appreciate this in a one-word answer so may not be what you are looking for.

For example, "The painting was a real mishmash of different styles and techniques".

from [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mishmash)

> a confused mixture of things

Comment: Hey, that's it....  No, wait.  It was hotchpotch. :D